Helm template Override namespace of dependency chart (bitnami chart)
I have a helm chart that i've created on my own, and it has dependencies listed for bitnami's postresql and common charts.
What is confusing me is that I am doing GitOps to generate the helm manifests in my build pipeline by running the helm template command and then argoCD is taking the helm manifests and deploying them.
The issue is that Release.Name is not being set on the dependency charts so all of the resources related to postresql are "release-name-" which I do not want. I am just trying to overwrite that to be a uniform name with my main chart which is having the Release.Name value properly set.
dependencies:
  - name: postgresql
    version: "15.4.0"
    repository: https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami
    condition: postgresql.enabled
  - name: common
    version: 2.x.x
    repository: https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami
    condition: postresql.enabled

I validated that I can overwrite values in the dependency charts by including them in my values.yaml file, but I can't seem to set the release name for these dependency charts no matter what I do and without that, it seems that I can't get rid of release-name- for my resources.
Does anyone know how to include the release name in the dependency charts?
